# Can't make a simple If Else statement work

Tags: javascript, if-statement, queryselector

Hello I'm making a simple counter that is counting to 3 every time i click the button. The counter works just fine, because I can see how he changes in the console. The problem is, my JS isn't affecting the CSS. When I delete the else statements and leave only one, this is the one that is working.

CSS. note: The strongAttackBtn and strongAttackBtnLoading are in the same div.

```
.strongAttackBtn {
    height: 50px;
    width: 150px;

    color: black;
    font-weight: 800;
}
.strongAttackBtnLoading {
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

JS

```
const strongAttackBtnLoading = document.querySelector('.strongAttackBtnLoading');    
const strongAttackBtn = document.querySelector('.strongAttackBtn');
let strongAttackCounter = 0;

if (strongAttackCounter === 3) {
    strongAttackBtnLoading.style.width = '150px';
} else if (strongAttackCounter === 2) {
    strongAttackBtnLoading.style.width = '100px';
} else if (strongAttackCounter === 1) {
    strongAttackBtnLoading.style.width = '50px';
} else if (strongAttackCounter === 0) {
    strongAttackBtnLoading.style.width = '0px';
}

strongAttackBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  strongAttackCounter++;
})
```

Comment: your if-statement block should be inside the event-listener.

Comment: Simple as that, i don't know what was I thinking. Thanks

Comment: also you could make your if/else one line `strongAttackBtnLoading.style.width = (strongAttackCounter < 150 ? strongAttackCounter * 50 : 150) + 'px';`

Comment: It works just great Lawrence. What does the ":" sign do? I don't understand why this code works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

You have to assign `CSS` to both DIVs and put your if statement code in the `addEventListener` click function.

```js
const strongAttackBtn = document.querySelector('.strongAttackBtn');
const strongAttackBtnLoading =document.querySelector('.strongAttackBtnLoading');
var strongAttackCounter = 0;
strongAttackBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  strongAttackCounter++;
  
  if (strongAttackCounter === 3) {
    strongAttackCounter=0; // set it to zero again;
    
    strongAttackBtnLoading.style.width = '150px';
    strongAttackBtn.style.width = '150px';
    
  } else if (strongAttackCounter === 2) {
  
      strongAttackBtnLoading.style.width = '100px';
      strongAttackBtn.style.width = '100px';
      
  } else if (strongAttackCounter === 1) {
  
      strongAttackBtnLoading.style.width = '50px';
      strongAttackBtn.style.width = '50px';
      
  } else if (strongAttackCounter === 0) {
  
      strongAttackBtnLoading.style.width = '0px';
      strongAttackBtn.style.width = '0px';
      
  }
})
```

```css
.strongAttackBtn {
    height: 50px;
    width: 150px;

    color: black;
    font-weight: 800;
}
.strongAttackBtnLoading {
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="strongAttackBtnLoading"><input class="strongAttackBtn" type="button" value="strongAttackBtn"></div>
```

Comment: I update the code I missed the Note part.